# Which way is it better to call ORM methods in Odoo 7?

Tags: orm, openerp-7, odoo

Let's say you have in your code an object of model 'account.invoice' and inside a method you want to update the partner. I noticed that you have two ways of calling the 'write' method on model 'res.partner'. You could either do :

```
invoice.partner_id.write({'name': 'Mister Test'})
```

OR

```
partner_obj = self.pool.get('res.partner')
partner_obj.write(cr, uid, invoice.partner_id.id, {'name': 'Mister Test'})
```

I always used the second way because it is the one that is always described in documentations. However, I discovered that the first way is also working and is shorter. Is it ok to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

When object is browse record than I direct write browse record object.write({'field_name': value})

```
invoice.partner_id.write({'name': 'Mister Test'})
```

This line give error because partner_id is a many2one field so it's store integer number. So you can’t use this.

For this you must to browse that partner_id and than you may to write on partner object.

And second point, if you want write something in invoice object than you can use this for example invoice.write({'field_name': value}) this will work.

Hope this make a sense.